# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'abi')

Tags: solidity, javascript

```js
const solc = require("solc");
const fs = require("fs");
const Web3 = require("web3");

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545"));

const fileContent = fs.readFileSync("demo.sol", "utf8");
console.log("File Content:\n", fileContent);

const input = {
  language: "Solidity",
  sources: {
    "demo.sol": {
      content: fileContent,
    },
  },
  settings: {
    outputSelection: {
      "*": {
        "*": ["*"],
      },
    },
  },
};

const output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));
console.log("Compilation Output:\n", output);

const ABI = output.contracts["demo.sol"]["demoContract"].abi;
const bytecode =
  output.contracts["demo.sol"]["demoContract"].evm.bytecode.object;

console.log("ABI : ", ABI);
console.log("Bytecode : ", bytecode);

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI);

let defaultAddress;

web3.eth.getAccounts().then((accounts) => {
  console.log("Accounts: ", accounts);
  defaultAddress = accounts[0];
  console.log("Default Address: ", defaultAddress);

  contract
    .deploy({ data: "0x" + bytecode }) // Ensure bytecode starts with "0x"
    .send({ from: defaultAddress, gas: 2000000 }) // Corrected gas limit
    .on("receipt", (receipt) => {
      console.log("Contract Address: ", receipt.contractAddress);
      // You can interact with the contract methods here if needed
      contract.methods.x().call((err, data) => {
        console.log("Initial Value : ", data);
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Deployment Error: ", error);
    });
});
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, and you didn't provide enough information. Please explain your target and the problem you are facing. You just provided the code.

Comment: what does `console.log("ABI : ", ABI);` prints? which line its exploding?